# How to prove the inequality using Jensen's inequlaity?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

[image]
How to prove the above inequality? I am learning probability by myself and it has been confusing me for days. Thanks!

Comment: Try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality?

Comment: Are you user @Tony http://math.stackexchange.com/q/938673/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a discrete random variable $X$ with the distribution $P(X=\log y_m)=p(m)$. Since $\sum_{m=1}^n p(m)=1$ and each $p(m)\geq 0$, this is a probability distribution.

Jensen's inequality states that $$\phi(\mathbb{E}[X])\leq \mathbb{E}[\phi(X)]$$ whenever $\phi$ is convex. Choose $\phi=e^x$. Plugging into the equation yields
$$
\begin{align*}
\exp(\sum_{m=1}^n p(m) \log y_m)&\leq \sum_{m=1}^n e^{\log y_m}p(m)\\
&= \sum_{m=1}^n p(m)y_m.
\end{align*}
$$
Simplifying the LHS by properties of exponents yields the desired inequality.